# Google Play Games Services saved games: Time Since Last Modified property?

Tags: c#, datetime, unity-game-engine, save, cloud

In the documentation it says "Timestamp in milliseconds generated by Google Play games services for when the saved game was last updated." I have a few questions and I can't find the answers online..

Does it return the time in UTC since epoch?

Does anyone have some examples?

I'm trying to add GPGS saved games to my app and wanted to check between the creation time of the local save file and the last modified time of the cloud save to see which one to load or save to the cloud.